# No Aplica efecto librería Animate CSS a elemento iframe

Tags: javascript

tengo una duda al usar la biblioteca Animate CSS  puedo aplicarla una sola vez pero quiero que al momento de dar click en el icono este aplique otro efecto de salida y es ahí donde no lo consigo.

```js
const tocar = document.getElementsByClassName("tocar")[0];
const btn = document.getElementById("mostrar")
const cerrar = document.querySelector(".cerrar")


function mostrar(){
  tocar.addEventListener("click",e=>{
    btn.style.display="block";
  
  })
}

function  close(){
  cerrar.addEventListener("click", e =>{
   btn.classList.add('animate__animated', 'animate__fadeOutDown')
   btn.style.display="none"
  })
  }

mostrar()
close()
```

```css
#mostrar{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Jan Kelly | A Creative Digital Agency</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <script src="iconosPro.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

   <div class="container-video ">
            <span class="tocar">toca aquí </span>
            <p id="mostrar" class="animate__animated animate__zoomInDown">Hola mundo</p>
            <br>
            <span class="cerrar">cerrar</span> 
      </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Entonces si se dan cuenta el cierre no me hace la animación, se supone que  se debe mandar llamar el selector y aplicarle la nueva clase pero no funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Deberías añadir y quitar las clases necesarias en los eventos de mostrar y close. En el evento close estás añadiendo dos clases, una de ellas la estarías duplicando y al mismo tiempo estás manteniendo la anterior.

Por otro lado, el evento de cerrar si que hace lo que quieres, lo que pasa es que la animación se está ejecutando y al ocultar con display:none no te da tiempo a verla.

Si añades una clase a modo de flag, puedes verificarla en un handler que proporciona la librería animate.css:

```js
const tocar = document.getElementsByClassName("tocar")[0];
const btn = document.getElementById("mostrar")
const cerrar = document.querySelector(".cerrar")


function mostrar() {
  tocar.addEventListener("click", e => {
    btn.classList.add('animate__zoomInDown')
    btn.classList.remove('animate__fadeOutDown', 'ocultar')
    btn.style.display = "block";
  })
}

function close() {
  cerrar.addEventListener("click", e => {
    btn.classList.remove('animate__zoomInDown')
    btn.classList.add('animate__fadeOutDown', 'ocultar')
  })
}

btn.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
  if (btn.classList.contains('ocultar')) {
    btn.style.display = "none"
  }
});

mostrar()
close()
```

```css
#mostrar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Jan Kelly | A Creative Digital Agency</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  <script src="iconosPro.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-video ">
    <span class="tocar">toca aquí </span>
    <p id="mostrar" class="animate__animated animate__zoomInDown">Hola mundo</p>
    <br>
    <span class="cerrar">cerrar</span>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```